# Какой параметр указывать в lock в моем случае?

Tags: c#, многопоточность

```
lock( ???? )
{
    ptk = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\likes\n.txt");
    File.WriteAllText(@"C:\likes\n.txt",Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(ptk) + "1"));
}
```

Какой параметр указывать в `lock` в моем случае? Чтоб содержимое фигурных скобок выполнялось при многопоточности не одновременно.

Comment: Если у вас идёт обращение к этому куску кода из разных потоков, то лучше синхронизировать сам метод, а не кусок кода следующим параметром `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]`. По крайней мере в моём случае это исключило даже редкие ошибки доступа к файлу из параллельных потоков.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы должны завести отдельное приватное поле (обычно типа `object`):

```
private readonly object _lockObj = new object();
```

И дальше использовать его:

```
lock (_lockObj)
{
    ptk = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\likes\n.txt");
    File.WriteAllText(@"C:\likes\n.txt",Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(ptk) + "1"));
}
```